# Reduce Video Size Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use Media Plugin to Pick video from ios and Android devices, but size of stream is very large,
my question is how reduce this stream to send to server.

```
   var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickVideoAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
       stream = file.GetStream();
       byte[] result;
       using (var streamReader = new MemoryStream())
       {
         stream.CopyTo(streamReader);
        result = streamReader.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the **CompressionQuality**, which is a value from 0 the most compressed all the way to 100 .

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new StoreVideoOptions
{
     CompressionQuality = 85,
     Quality = VideoQuality.Medium
});
```

### Update

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
```

```
  public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        using (var dstream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            dstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: I want to select video from gallery and compress it , not record video or open camera.

Comment: It did not affect much, original video size 3175025 after compress 3095006
try CompressionLevel.Optimal and CompressionLevel.Fastest the same size after compression

Comment: The video will be blurry if compress it too much .

Comment: we use video with size 200 Mb and above that take much time to send to server so we interest in reducing size of video up to 70 %  at least.

Comment: If so you could compress it as zip , check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netcore-3.1